# Do I need to add GTM initializing for every pages?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

Do I need to add GTM initializing(the following code) for every page?
Or Do I just need to add that at only the app.js file?

```
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'
 
const tagManagerArgs = {
    gtmId: 'GTM-000000',
    events: {
        sendUserInfo: 'userInfo'
    }
}
 
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize it once in the app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to initialize the GTM code once and then use `TagManager.dataLayer()` to send you data on the page you need.

You can read more in the document with sample code.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module#datalayer